# Does this recursive sequence have an explicit formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, limsup-and-liminf

My recursive sequence is defined as $f\left(2n\right)=\frac{f\left(2n-1\right)}{2}$, $f\left(2n+1\right)=f\left(2n\right)+\frac{1}{2}$, and $f\left(1\right)=0$. I see that the $\liminf=\frac{1}{2}$ and the $\limsup=1$, but I do not know if that helps me find an explicit formula for the sequence.

Comment: Have you computed some dozens of terms?  What did you learn?  What have you tried?  I find an interesting pattern that gives an explicit formula.  Of course, it needs proving.

Comment: Hint: Let $g(n)=f(2n)$. Then $g(n+1)=g(n)/2+1/4$.

Comment: @RossMillikan, yes I have. That is how I came up with the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ but thank you.

Comment: Did you subtract $f(n)$ from $0.5$ for odd $n$ and from $1$ for even $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} n \text{ even } ~&:~ \frac 12 f(n-1) \\ n \text{ odd } ~&:~ f(n - 1) + \frac 12 \end{cases}$$

So for odd $n$,

$$f(n) = \frac 12 f(n - 2) + \frac 12$$

Which is just an affine equation, so yes it has a simple solution.  If you want to convert it to a linear equation, then

$$f(n + 2) = \frac 12 f(n) + \frac 12$$

And subtract the last 2 equations to get:

$$f(n + 2) - \frac 32 f(n) + \frac 12 f(n - 2) = 0$$